# android student topic swipe refresh layout

Tags: java, android, xml, api

I'm Working on the android app so, the error is whenever i swipe up the data has been lost. How to get data back after swipe the layout?
Given below is the code is the code for swipe refresh.
and the data is coming from the api's (from the server).

```
this.swipeRefreshLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.swipeRefresh);
        this.swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.colorPrimary);
        this.swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                        new SelectData().execute(did,course);
                        Log.e("logo", course);
                    }
                }, 1000);
            }
        });
```

Comment: why are you calling recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE); --> hide your recyclerview from screen ??!!

Comment: You need to return the code instead of returning a void.